# Does an evil clerics holy symbol, if dropped and then found, have an evil aura for the purposes of Detect Evil?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, aura

Does an evil clerics holy symbol, if dropped and then found, have an evil aura for the purposes of Detect Evil?

Comment: if you wanted to do it simply for 'role playing effect' you could look at the HD of its previous owner if in fact the previous owner was evil and then use the rule for lingering aura as per the Detect Evil spell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing says a typical (un)holy symbol has any particular aura. Impossible to prove a negative, but, well, neither *detect good* (*evil*) nor (un)holy symbols mention it, which is pretty much where it should be if it existed.

Particular, special (un)holy symbols may very much be exceptions, though, especially if they’re magical. The books don’t actually bother to define such special (un)holy symbols very often—kind of surprisingly, in my view—but I’m pretty sure some examples exist.

Comment: Hmm... is there anything about an aura of a person sort of... tainting objects? Carrying around the holy symbol for a few years might contaminate it a bit?

Comment: @NeomerArcana Not that I’m aware of. Detecting associations and history of objects is generally beyond the scope and power of *detect evil*; see [*object reading*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/objectReading.htm) or, in the extreme case, [*legend lore*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/legendLore.htm) for things that have the power to see that deeply. That said, it’s certainly a reasonable thing to add to your campaign world if it fits. I can’t imagine any situation where it would harm the game to make that a thing, particularly for “aligned-ish” items like (un)holy symbols.

Comment: Here's some special (un)holy symbols for you:

Special (un)Holy Symbols - Complete Champion p.133;

Greater (un)Holy Symbols - Defenders of the Faith (3.0) p.26;

True (un)Holy Symbols - Planar Handbook p.71;

Domain (un)Holy Symbols - Dragon Magizine issues 327, 329, 331